# EC2's Under Auto-Scaling won't scale even if not healthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache2

EC2 under Auto-Scaling won't scale maybe because due to a memory problem. My autoscaling setup checks the CPU since the memory by default can't be added to the cloudwatch metric. Any recommended ideas for me to have my servers auto scale with the above scenario?

[syslogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kSR1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor the memory usage your EC2 instances by installing the [CloudWatch Monitoring Scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) and setting them up as cron job to publish detailed metrics about CPU, memory/swap utilisation, and disk space utilisation. (Do it in CloudFormation so you have these scripts set up for every instance). Then you can create a normal CloudWatch alarm based on this data.